# Grails with Java JUnit tests

Tags: grails, junit

I have some Java code in my Grails project.
I have JUnit tests for them written in Java.
How can I add those tests to my Grails application?

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 3 you can drop unit tests written in Java under `src/test/groovy` and they will be picked up and executed when tests are run (`./gradlew test`, for example).  If you really want them under `src/test/java/` that can be made to work with a little extra config in your `build.gradle`, but `src/test/groovy/` will Just Work™.